# Cannot connect to iPhone Personal Hotspot on MacBook

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, tethering

It seems that connecting to my iPhone's Personal Hotspot from my MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina) via Wi-Fi does not work, though connecting via Bluetooth does work, and likewise connecting from my iPad via Wi-Fi is no problem.

The error when I try to connect to my iPhone's hotspot via Wi-Fi (after waiting a few seconds while it attempts) is a pretty generic one; see below. What could be going wrong here? Maybe an obscurer issue with network settings?

[image]

Comment: Change the name of your personal hotspot and try it. Also, put new password and check it.

Comment: @Udhy No luck I'm afraid. Same issue.